# Primefaces SelectOneMenu reselect option in deleted row within DataTable in new row

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a selectonemenu within a datatable column. The selected options are messed up when I delete a row and it doesn't seems to reflect the value in the backend bean. For example, I selected Item A in the first row, then add another row and select Item B in the second row, then when I delete the first row, the second row is move up with Item A selected, but the backend value of second row is still Item B and Item A is removed from the collection.

```
            <p:dataTable id="insertDetailTable" styleClass="data-table"
                rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="receivingDetail"
                value="#{receivingController.receiving.receivingDetails}">

                <p:column headerText="Item">
                    <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="input" id="item"
                        value="#{receivingDetail.item}" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Item is required" converter="itemConverter">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select an item" itemValue="#{null}"
                            noSelectionOption="true" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{receivingController.items}" var="item"
                            itemLabel="#{item.code} - #{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}" />
                        <p:ajax update="insertDetailTable" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>

                <p:column styleClass="action-cell">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Add"
                            action="#{receivingController.insertDetail('insert')}"
                            immediate="true" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                        action="#{receivingController.deleteDetail('insert', receivingDetail)}"
                        immediate="true">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation"
                            message="Do you wish to remove the selected detail?"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

The backend code of adding a new row and deleting a row:

```
public void insertDetail(String owner) {
    ReceivingDetail receivingDetail = new ReceivingDetail();
    receivingDetail.setReceiving(receiving);
    receivingDetail.setQtyStored(new BigDecimal("0.00"));
    receiving.getReceivingDetails().add(receivingDetail);

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (owner.equals(OWNER_INSERT)) {
        context.update("insertForm");
        context.execute("PF('insertDialogWV').show();");
    } else if (owner.equals(OWNER_UPDATE)) {
        context.update("updateForm");
        context.execute("PF('updateDialogWV').show();");
    }
}

public void deleteDetail(String owner, ReceivingDetail receivingDetail) {
    receiving.getReceivingDetails().remove(receivingDetail);
    ItemService itemSvc = (ItemService) getService(ItemService.class);
    setItems(itemSvc.find());

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (owner.equals(OWNER_INSERT)) {
        context.update("insertForm");
        context.execute("PF('insertDialogWV').show();");
    } else if (owner.equals(OWNER_UPDATE)) {
        context.update("updateForm");
        context.execute("PF('updateDialogWV').show();");
    }
}
```

Any idea what went wrong with my code?

I am using Primefaces 5 and JSF 2.2.

This is the first time I posting a question, not sure did I do it right, let me know if I need to correct anything, thanks in advance.

**Edited:**
Just in case this information is required, the datatable resides within a dialog as such.

```
<h:form id="insertForm">
    <p:dialog id="insertDialog" widgetVar="insertDialogWV" modal="true"
        draggable="false" resizable="false" header="Add Record"
        closable="false">

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed immediate="true" in the command button and it works, the table select and show the value according to the backend bean properly.